# Cron Job - Copy JSON API Results to File on Server via PHP

Tags: php, cron

There are some similar posts with the same issue and I've tried a number of what they have proposed with no solution.  I'm trying to save an json result from an API once a day so that I don't have to constantly query the api since the figure only updates once a day.

I have a Cron Job setup to run a .php file which should copy the results into a .json file but it isn't working and the Cron is successfully running.  I have allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include enabled in my php.ini file.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    $site = 'https://api.carbondoomsday.com/api/co2/?limit=1';
    $homepage = file_get_contents($site);
    $filename = 'cotwo.json';
    $handle = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($handle,$homepage);
    echo "Success";
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

OR

```
﻿<?php

file_put_contents('test.json', file_get_contents('https://api.carbondoomsday.com/api/co2/?limit=1'));

?>
```

these should work but nothing is happening.

Comment: tested it with out cron?

Comment: You need the full path for the $filename.

Comment: So the full web address? It won't work if its in the same folder like that?

Comment: no he means the local path not the remote `$filename = '/full/path/location/cotwo.json';`

Comment: so if it was in the main directory it would look like 

$filename = 'public_html/cotow.json'?

Comment: absolute server path not relative local one

Comment: This worked - thank you!